# Changing the URL for blogs on Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I was wondering if it was possible to change the default URL for blogs. Our client has recipes and would like it to be `mydomain/recipes` instead of the `mydomain/blogs`

If not, is it possible to copy the `blog.liquid` template and rework that somehow on its own custom page? Ultimately, is there any way to achieve this behavior without having to move the recipes to some other platform?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have `/blogs/recipes` but you can't have just `/recipes`.

There is no way in Shopify to change this no matter what you try.

If he is concerned about SEO the `/blogs/recipes` won't affect it or it least it wont affect it as hard as he think.

The best you can do is generate a proxy page with an App and add the products there, but the URL will be something like `/a/recipes`, which will be an overkill for just an url.

Shopify does not support URL rewrite rules, so the bottom line is - you can't achieve this with only Shopify.

You can create a separate page that pulls the blogs posts from Shopify if this is really important for your client, but once again - it's an overkill.